# Ruby code doesn't work

Tags: ruby, if-statement, methods, each

/Users/danielwheeler/Desktop/Screen Shot 2015-09-26 at 13.18.16.png

I'm trying to make a method that takes a number as an input an converts it into a string. Not sure what's wrong.

Error message from sublime is:

```
/Users/danielwheeler/Desktop/code/projects/learn_to_program/ch10-nothing-new/english_number.rb:30:in `block in english_number': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from /Users/danielwheeler/Desktop/code/projects/learn_to_program/ch10-nothing-new/english_number.rb:23:in `each'
    from /Users/danielwheeler/Desktop/code/projects/learn_to_program/ch10-nothing-new/english_number.rb:23:in `each_with_index'
    from /Users/danielwheeler/Desktop/code/projects/learn_to_program/ch10-nothing-new/english_number.rb:23:in `english_number'
    from /Users/danielwheeler/Desktop/code/projects/learn_to_program/ch10-nothing-new/english_number.rb:44:in `<main>'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: https://github.com/d9nny/learn_to_program/commit/1e122c5e093979f5318366fd1ce86ea9a7b55f24

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't provide a link to your code. And especially, don't provide a link to your code in a comment. Instead, reduce your code to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem you're asking about. Links rot and comments are for clarifications, not code. You need minimal sample input to demonstrate the problem also, and the expected output. As is, your question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your codes and found some problems:

```
 num_array.reverse.each_with_index { |value , index|
    if index % 3 == 0 && num_array[index] != 0 
      num_string = num_string << ones_place[value-1]
    elsif index % 3 == 0 && value > 0 && num_array[index] != 0
      num_string = num_string << other_place[index/3] << ones_place[value-1]
    elsif index % 3 == 1
      num_string = num_string << tens_place[value-1]
    elsif index & 3 == 2
      num_string = num_string << other_place[0] << ones_place[value-1]
    end
  }
```

`ones_place[value-1]` is possibly nil, you try to add nil to string, so `TypeError` raised. if `ones_place[value-1]` is nil, you should change it into string, just need to use `to_s` method or use `+` to add strings together.

```
"" << nil
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String

"" << nil.to_s
=> ""
```

I modify the code as below, the script can works, no errors found, but I don't know the result is right or not, you should check it by yourself.

```
  num_array.reverse.each_with_index { |value , index|
    puts "#{value} and #{index}"
    if index % 3 == 0 && num_array[index] != 0
      num_string = num_string + ones_place[index-1]
    elsif index % 3 == 0 && value > 0 && num_array[index] != 0
      num_string = num_string + other_place[index/3] + ones_place[index-1]
    elsif index % 3 == 1
      num_string = num_string + tens_place[index-1]
    elsif index & 3 == 2
      num_string = num_string + other_place[0] + ones_place[index-1]
    end
  }
```

I suggest you add some debug code to your script, it can help you find problems as soon as possible.